# Doing a spring experiment, and need to find the stretch required

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, projectile, spring

I'm doing an experiment where I have to calculate the stretch of a spring needed for it to launch itself into a trashcan located some distance away.
The spring is located on the edge of a ramp that is 1.13 m high. The angle of the ramp is 30 degrees above horizontal.  The spring constant of the spring is 175 N/m. The trashcan is located a horizontal distance 5.85 m away, height of the trashcan can be ignored.  I must find the stretch (x) of the spring that will accomplish this.

At first I thought I must solve for time of flight but there are too many variables involved. For instance, I don't know the initial velocity of the spring. If I could solve for time, then I could use it to find Vx (horizontal component of velocity), and then use the angle to find V. Then I would do Ee = Ek (elastic potential was converted to kinetic the instant the spring was released) and finally solve for the stretch (x). 
I tried to use the range equation: R = (v^2/g)sin2θ, but that is only for projectiles that land at the same height. Any guidance on how to approach this?

Comment: You state *height of the trashcan can be ignored* but then later disregard your range equation because it *is only for projectiles that land at the same height.* These seem contradictory to me.

Comment: @BMS, the spring is fired from a height (the ramp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Find the launch speed and time using $$x(t) = (v \cos \theta) t$$ and $$ y(t) = h + (v \sin\theta) t - \frac{1}{2} g t^2$$
2. Find the stretch using $$ \frac{1}{2} k \delta^2 = \frac{1}{2} m v^2 $$

Done!

Comment: Where was the first equation derived from? And I can't use it because time and velocity are unknown.

Comment: Projectile motion.

Comment: for that I would need to know v or t

Comment: You have two equations. Distance $x$ and distance $y$ and you have two uknowns, $v$ and $t$.